# Unity: Cant switch a scroll panel to vertical instead of horizontal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scroll

Ok, I am having a problem with a Unity scroll panel in C#. I downloaded this character picker that consists of a script attached to a scroll panel from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBsGhYuTavA

It works very well but problem is I cant make it scroll vertically instead of horizontal. I have checked the "vertical" boolean instead of horizontal on the actual scroll panel then in the script I have changed the places that based off x values to y values.

I commented where, here is the script:

```
float[] distance;

    bool dragging = false;

    int minButtonNum;
    int currentSelectedPly = -1;

    public float objectScale = 1.7f;
    public int bttnDistance = 300;

    void OnEnable() {
        //txtGeneralCash.text = "" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("money", 0);
    }

    void Start(){
        distance = new float[prefab.Length];

        //instatiate the prefab
        for(int i=0; i<prefab.Length;i++){
            prefab[i] =  Instantiate(prefab[i],center.transform.position,camInUse.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            prefab [i].transform.SetParent(panel.transform);
            Vector3 pos = prefab[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
            pos.x += (i * bttnDistance); //**CHANGED TO POS.Y
            prefab [i].GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition = pos; 
        }
    }

    void Update(){
        //calculate the relative distance
        for(int i=0;i<prefab.Length;i++){
            distance [i] = Mathf.Abs (center.transform.position.x - prefab [i].transform.position.x); //CHANGED THESE TO .Y
        }

        float minDistance = Mathf.Min (distance);

        // Aplly the scale to object
        for(int a=0;a<prefab.Length;a++){
            if (minDistance == distance [a]) {
                minButtonNum = a;

                //this is when each char is selected !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                if(minButtonNum != currentSelectedPly){
                    //lookAtPrice (minButtonNum);
                    scaleButtonCenter (minButtonNum);
                    currentSelectedPly = minButtonNum;
                    txtName.text = prefab [minButtonNum].GetComponent<CharacterProperty> ().nameObj;
                    bgMat.color = prefab [minButtonNum].GetComponent<CharacterProperty> ().color;
                }
            }
        }

        // if the users aren't dragging the lerp function is called on the prefab
        if(!dragging){
            LerpToBttn (currentSelectedPly* (-bttnDistance));
        }

    }

    /*
     *  Lerp the nearest prefab to center 
     */
    void LerpToBttn(int position){
        float newX = Mathf.Lerp (panel.anchoredPosition.x,position,Time.deltaTime*7f); //CHANGED TO .Y
        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2 (newX,panel.anchoredPosition.y);
        panel.anchoredPosition = newPosition;
    }

    /*
     * Set the scale of the prefab on center to 2, other to 1
     */
    public void scaleButtonCenter (int minButtonNum){
        for (int a = 0; a < prefab.Length; a++) {
            if (a == minButtonNum) {
                StartCoroutine (ScaleTransform(prefab [a].transform,prefab [a].transform.localScale,new Vector3 (objectScale,objectScale,objectScale)));
            } else {
                StartCoroutine (ScaleTransform(prefab [a].transform,prefab [a].transform.localScale,new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f)));
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * If the prefab is not free, show the price button


    /*
     * Courutine for change the scale
     */
    IEnumerator ScaleTransform(Transform transformTrg,Vector3 initScale,Vector3 endScale){
        float completeTime = 0.2f;//How much time will it take to scale
        float currentTime = 0.0f;
        bool done = false;

        while (!done){
            float percent = currentTime / completeTime;
            if (percent >= 1.0f){
                percent = 1;
                done = true;
            }
            transformTrg.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(initScale, endScale, percent);
            currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by the canvas, set dragging to true for preventing lerp when users are dragging
     */
    public void StartDrag(){
        dragging = true;
    }

    /*
     * Called by the canvas, set dragging to true for preventing lerp when users are dragging
     */
    public void EndDrag(){
        dragging = false;
    }

    /*
     * Called when character is selected, it change the player model
     */
    public void CharacterSelected(){
        bool oneEnable = false;
        string nameSelected = prefab [currentSelectedPly].GetComponent<CharacterProperty> ().name;
        nameSelected = nameSelected.Split('(')[0];
        GameObject player = GameObject.Find ("CharactersPlayer");
        if(player != null){
            foreach (Transform child in player.transform) {
                if (child.gameObject.name == nameSelected) {
                    child.gameObject.SetActive (true);
                    oneEnable = true;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("SelectedPlayer", nameSelected);

                } else {
                    child.gameObject.SetActive (false);
                }
            }

            // if no one was selected
            if (oneEnable == false) {
                player.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ive gone through it several times and I don't know why just changing the values from .x to .y does not work. I get a bunch of glitching and the characters do stack up vertically, but they move off the screen when i try to scroll.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried asking the guy who wrote the script?

Comment: Yes, waiting for his response